# WPF ItemsControl - Change focus when item added

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamically-generated

I have an `ObservableCollectiong<StringWrapper>` (StringWrapper per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062045/how-can-i-bind-an-observablecollection-to-textboxes-in-a-datatemplate)) named Paragraphs bound to an ItemsControl whose ItemTemplate is just a TextBox bound to `StringWrapper.Text`.

**XAML**

```
<ItemsControl Name="icParagraphs" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Paragraphs, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Name="tbParagraph" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="False" Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Grid.Column="0" KeyUp="tbParagraph_KeyUp" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**C#**

```
public class StringWrapper
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public StringWrapper()
    {
        Text = string.Empty;
    }

    public StringWrapper(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so when I press enter in a TextBox, I insert a StringWrapper in my ObservableCollection after the StringWrapper bound to the TextBox that's currently focused, which generates a new TextBox.  So far, my code does this, though there are a couple glitches to work out.

My question is, *how do I then set the focus to the newly generated TextBox?*  As far as I can tell, the control generation happens after the function that inserts the string returns.

I looked for something like an ItemsControl.ItemsSourceChanged event, but, at least, that name doesn't exist.  I also tried attaching a handler to ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged, but that too seemed to fire before the TextBox was generated.  Last, since the ItemsControl.Template is a StackPanel, I looked for a StackPanel.ControlAdded event, but couldn't find that either.

Ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Cool, moved my comment to an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: I have the same issue but couldn't really get the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to handle `CollectionChanged` and then schedule the focus action to occur in the future using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` with a priority of `Loaded`. That should give the `ItemsControl` an opportunity to generate a container and perform layout.

Comment: Could you please explain a little how to use the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke? Sorry not a xaml developer, if you show with little code will be really helpful

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    if (list.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        var lastTextBox = list.Last(x => x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == "MyTextBox");

                        if (lastTextBox != null)
                        {
                            lastTextBox.Focus();
                        }
                    }
                }), DispatcherPriority.Loaded);